# IIS duplicating responses

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I use IIS 7 on my server. When Testing (Locally).

It would apprear as though IIS sends the request once but the response twice.

I know this because Fiddler logs 1 request but after the request I can note the following:

1. Either inserts commands on the database are duplicated (2 Entries but Clicked the button once).
2. Or error messages are duplicated. Example of error output :

The server rejected one or more recipient addresses. The server response was: 554 5.7.1 <`_EmailVariable_`>: Relay access denied The server rejected one or more recipient addresses. The server response was: 554 5.7.1 <`_EmailVariable_`>: Relay access denied

How can I check what the problem is, and how can I fix it.

The catch (After the try) of my vb code is as follows:

```
Catch Ex As Exception
    If Ex.Message.ToLower = "the server rejected one or more recipient addresses. the server response was: 554 5.7.1 <" + _EmailVariable_ + ">: relay access denied" Then
        Response.Write("In this error block!")
    Else
        Response.Write(ex.Message)
        'If Ex.Message.ToLower = "the transport lost its connection to the server." Then
        '    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "", "alert('PROBLEM: Please try again.')", True)
        'Else
        '    Response.Write(Ex.Message)
        'End If
    End If

    'ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "", "alert('The following Error Occured. [" & Ex.Message.Replace(vbcrlf, "") & "]. If this is the first time you see this error please contact Clive or Jacques.')", True)
End Try
```

I just want to make it clear, I understand the error that follows and my question is not pertaining to the error. I want to fix the IIS or even VB plugins that cause the request to execute twice but only logs one request.!

[Here you can see my actual fiddler request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsVEE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

My buttons that were handling the request didn't have an Id.

So Visual Studio automatically added a `onclick` event which it usually wouldn't do if the button had an Id.

So very simply it would appear to me as though when I clicked the button it would send the post back request (as per the normal for vb) and handle the response and when it was ready to send the actual response it handled the `onclick` event for the button thus ending in a duplicate response.